# Asymptotic in hypergeometric distribution.

Tags: probability, analysis

Assume $n_1 + n_2 = n$ and $M_1 + M_2 = M$. then 
$$\frac{C_{M_1}^{n_1}C_{M_2}^{n_2}}{C_{M}^{n}} \rightarrow \frac{n!}{n_1! n_2!}p^{n_1}(1-p)^{n_2}$$
when $M\rightarrow \infty$ and $M_1 \rightarrow \infty$ and $\frac{M_1}{M} \rightarrow p$

---

I do some calculation, $\frac{C_{M_1}^{n_1}C_{M_2}^{n_2}}{C_{M}^{n}} = \frac{n!}{n_1!n_2!}\frac{(M_1-n_1+1)\cdots M_1 (M_2-n_2+1) \cdots M_2}{(M-n+1) \cdots M}$

then I don't know how to do next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First observe that $\frac{M_1-n_1+1}{M} = \frac{M_1}{M} = p$ asymptotically and equal to $1-p$ for $M_2$. Then divide both the numerator and denominator of

$\frac{(M_1-n_1+1)\cdots M_1 (M_2-n_2+1) \cdots M_2}{(M-n+1) \cdots M}$

with $M^n$ and use the above relations to conclude that the denominator tends to 1 and the numerator to $p^{n_1}(1-p)^{n_2}$